# SpEL how to use a parameter in method call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I have an application using Spring Scheduler and I want to get the cron expression from a database. I have it working without a parameter but I require a parameter in the call to get the right schedule from the database (schedule name). I have tried a few different versions without success. Please see both working and non-working code below as an example of what I am trying to do.

The following code is working:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    SchedulePropertiesRepository spRepository;

    @Bean   
    public String getCronExpression() {
        ScheduleProperties sp = spRepository.findByScheduleName("date");
        return sp.getCron();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{@getCronExpression}")
private void cronSchedule() {
     log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}
```

However I want to pass a parameter for the schedule name eg:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    SchedulePropertiesRepository spRepository;

    @Bean   
    public String getCronExpression(String scheduleName) {
        ScheduleProperties sp = spRepository.findByScheduleName(scheduleName);
        return sp.getCron();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{@getCronExpression('date')}")
private void cronSchedule() {
     log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}
```

But this me the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduler' defined in file [Scheduler.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lparen(()'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at main(GeniusPrintDocExtractorApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lparen(()'
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.EmbeddedValueResolver.resolveStringValue(EmbeddedValueResolver.java:56) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processScheduled(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$null$1(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:362) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$2(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:362) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lparen(()'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:135) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:61) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:33) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpressions(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:121) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseTemplate(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:62) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:49) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:142) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way of doing what I require?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@getCronExpression` is not a method call, it is a reference to a bean by name. See [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-bean-references).

Instead, remove the `@Bean` annotation, name the configuration bean so you can refer to it, then call the method.

```
@Configuration("myApplicationConfig")
@EnableScheduling
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    SchedulePropertiesRepository spRepository;

    public String getCronExpression(String scheduleName) {
        ScheduleProperties sp = spRepository.findByScheduleName(scheduleName);
        return sp.getCron();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{@myApplicationConfig.getCronExpression('date')}")
private void cronSchedule() {
     log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. I thought that might be the case abd tried something similar but not quite right. This has done the trick.